# How do I run Flyway Migrations on Heroku?

Tags: java, maven, heroku, flyway

I'm using [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org) for migrations on a Maven Java project.  I am currently working to make it possible to deploy to Heroku.

On my local machine I am using the Maven Flyway plugin to run migrations:

`$> mvn clean compile flyway:migrate`

To do the same on heroku, I would normally try:

`$> heroku run mvn flyway:migrate`

However, mvn is not available after the build phase, so this yields an error (`mvn: command not found`)

**How can I run my flyway migrations on Heroku?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to create a small class in your application that uses the FlywayDB Java API. It might look like this:

```
class Migrator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ...
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(url, user, password);
    flyway.migrate();
  }
}
```

Then create an entry in your `Procfile` like this:

```
migrate: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Migrator
```

And finally run it as needed with `heroku run migrate`.

The reason Heroku does not include Maven in the slug (i.e. at runtime) is because the `.m2` directory is not retained. If Maven were included, and you then ran a `mvn` command, it would first have to download the internet. The `.m2` directory is not retained because it would make the slug size too large.

Comment: "it would first have to download the internet" <3

Comment: Or you could simply run the migration on application startup :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-database-migrations-for-java-apps#using-flyway) using the Maven plugin is not recommended for running Flyway migrations.

Within the documentation there are two alternatives:

- [Running Flyway automatically with Spring](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-database-migrations-for-java-apps#running-flyway-automatically-with-spring)
- [Running Flyway with
  the Java API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-database-migrations-for-java-apps#running-flyway-with-the-java-api) (Also see @codefinger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31214174/5955911))